# Looking for possible anthology book where one story featured a bird in a diaper and bonnet

Tags: story-identification, books, comics

It was a book I remember seeing a few pages of when I was young but of which I can't remember more than a few details.

There was one story about a little monster girl, whose mom told her that old "if you keep making that face it will stay that way" except she was making the face of a cute little girl with pigtails... since she was a monster of some sort.

Another story or comic was of a duck or a chicken? Some bird I think that was big and wearing a bonnet and diaper, and he was with his mom. Some people attacked his mom I think and he got protective. Sort of a weird norma/norman bates situation.

It had a ton of illustrations and I remember it mostly being black and white. I'm pretty sure it was some anthology book, maybe with works from different creators. I don't have much else to go on, but I think if I saw pictures I would know.

Maybe somebody knows what I'm talking about? Or maybe I dreamed it all up?